# What is a Giant's Diet?

Tags: biology, creature-design

If an average human is 5'10" (1.8m), when scaled to be roughly 50 ft (15 m) how much food would it need to remain healthy?

Let's also assume there are three types of this giant; carnivorous, herbivorous and omnivorous. What would be the dietary requirements of each?

Comment: On an earth-like planet, right?

Comment: Ignoring what, exactly?

Comment: For those answering: Note that the giant is x8.6 as tall, making him x630 as massive as our baseline human (since he would scale depth and width as well).

Comment: Presumably, the three types of giant would have the same dietary requirements; they just go about meeting those in different ways.

Comment: Also: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: @Theraot - yeah. Earth.

Comment: @Molot - ignoring the fact that a giant humanoid, of exactly human proportions, would be very unfortunate for said giant :P

Comment: The first part of the question can be answered, and is a good question for this site. The second part is too broad, requiring the answerer to generate types of food for each diet. You should specify what you want each of the three types of diet to eat for it to be narrow enough here.

Comment: @Kingledion - well, I included the second part superficially; it was more so a means to deviate from answers that would mention eating humans, though now I think about it, I could have just said that...

Comment: Giants like this would only evolve on low gravity Worlds which have suitable flora and fauna to sustain them... is there magic involved?

Comment: What is an eating "requirement"? Human's don't follow requirements and we pay for it with health problems, but we survive. The giants would probably pass down knowledge of what is edible generation to generation and they would attempt to find a renewable source. They would be mega farmers and mega ranchers. See how intelligence matters? Need more info

Comment: @kingelodion you removed "ignoring" part. Why? Wouldn't it be better to include OP explanation from comment?

Comment: @Smurtagh - I don't need anything intelligence based. I merely want to know how much food would sustain a large individual, given his or her available foodstuffs.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. It is very clear what the question is about.

Comment: Since it is clearly magical (because of the anatomy) and that the magic is clearly trying to produce a creature that behaves as if a human in a miniature world, wouldn't the giant just eat giant versions of a normal human's meals, or its equivalent by weight of human foods? The energy and nutrient discrepancy would then be compensated for by the magic.

Comment: *"What is a Giant's Diet?"* ... pah, everyone knows that giants eat children and princesses. "Fee-fi-fo-fum..."

Comment: @Recelica as Nex Terren said, the giant would eat about 630 times (or is it only 138?) as much as we do of about the same kind of stuff. Anything from vegan quiche to steak dinners. (Quiche made with free range vegans of course.)

Comment: Why they eat *Human Beans* of course. #BFG

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The giant is 8.6 times taller than the human. This means that your giant is roughly 630 times heavier than a human. The square cube law is your biggest problem here. Your giant is simply too big to hold his own weight up. Good news for you, your giant is magical and doesn't care about that particular piece of physics.

Fortunately, 630 times greater mass does not mean 630 times greater food. If this relationship were true, large animals would never be able to find enough food, and mice would eat a kernel of corn per week. The real relationship is less than linear.

[Kleiber's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law) states that the metabolism of a creature is proportional to its body weight to the 0.75 power. **GM = C*GW<sup>0.75</sup>** In this GM and GW are giant metabolism and weight, and C is a constant number depending on the type of animal.

If we say that the average man weighs 80 kilograms and, requires 2000 calories per day we can write this as:
 $ 2000 \frac{calories}{day} = C*80 Kg$

We can also say that the giant weighs about 50400 Kg. We can solve both equations for C and equate them, and substitute in GW=50400.

$\frac{GM}{50400^{0.75}}=\frac{2000}{70^{0.75}}$

Solving for giant metabolism gives us 280000 calories per day, **138 times as much as is needed for an average human.**

A pound of beef has roughly 1100 calories. It would take 250 pounds of beef per day to feed this giant. If the giant doesn't eat entrails and bones, that comes out to a whole cow every other day. A pound of grain comes out to roughly 1400 calories. It would eat 200 pounds of grain per day.

*Note: I made edits to calories in grain. My original figures were incorrect.*

Note that these are rough estimates and do not take into account SOOO many other factors. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law#/media/File:Kleiber1947.jpg) has a link to Kleiber's original chart. Kleiber didn't see any animals who have 10 times higher metabolism than his law predicted, but he did examine a few who were half or double his predictions.

**In conclusion: An omnivorous giant would eat a quarter cow and 100 pounds of grain per day or twice that, or half that.**

Comment: "What will you have for dinner?" "Half a cow and only 30 pounds of grain - I am on a diet, you know"

Comment: Not necessarily true that the giant could not hold themselves up. There were two-legged dinosaurs almost that tall. Clearly some structural "architectural" changes would have to take place to a human skeleton and proportions would be different, but a 40+ foot tall biped is indeed physically possible.

Comment: @JBiggs Which ones? Can you give me a reference? T-Rex was 6 tons or so. The giant is 50 tons.

Comment: Argentinasaurus was 100 tons (albeit 4 legged, but that does mean that at least one leg was carrying at least 25 tons). Some studies mention that Spinosaurus (2-legged carnivorous) could be up to 20 tons.

Comment: @njzk2 Humans have a bunch of muscles and bone structure devoting to giving us stable walking balance. Having 4 legs makes that unnecessary. This giant is still twice as large as spinosaurus.

Comment: @BobTheAverage yeah, that's a pretty big giant (and also spinosaurus and friends have tails to help balance. Keeping a body vertical on such a height and just 2 feet is hard)

Comment: Height/weight ratios in humans do not follow the cube-power law, but rather use a lower power of around 2.7-2.8 (IIRC), this slightly reduces the weight requirement.

Comment: @BobTheAverage, you are ASSUMING this giant is 50 tons. That's because you are ASSUMING that a scaled up human would be proportionally identical to a scaled down human. There is no way this would be the case. My point is that structural changes would have had to be made to even think about a 50 foot tall "human" -shape, proportion, etc. 50 feet is really above "suspension of disbelief" range for a fantasy giant, but you can't just scale up a human in any case.

Comment: @JackAidley Can you provide a source?

Comment: @BobTheAverage: Not offhand, and I'm afraid I don't care to spend the time to go hunting. But the Wikipedia BMI page suggests the exponent should be 2.6 for children but actually less than 2 for adults (!), based on this paper: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ajpa.20107/abstract

Comment: This answer could be adapted to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/83202/809) - @BobTheAverage maybe you will adapt and post it?

Comment: BobTheAverage, to make @JackAidley 's point more clear, look at a toddler. If we scale a toddler to adult height are they equal in terms of proportions? No, of course not. Even if we compare a 5' tall adult to an 8' tall adult, the proportions aren't exactly the same when scaled to the same height.

Comment: @JustSnilloc The comment was clear. I just am not sure if I really believe it or not. This is a magical giant, a completely impossible creature. Extrapolating trends that apply to regular sized humans is dubious at best, and adjusting imprecise models doesn't necessarily make them better.

Answer (score 5):

So, basing these calculations on the dietary guidelines released by the US department of health for 2015-2020, and the x630 mass factor given by @Nex Terren in their comment, these are the recommended daily allowances for a giant:

```
Calories: 1260000 - 1890000
Protein: 28980 - 32760 g
Carb: 81900 g
Fiber: 17640 - 19404 g
Linoleic acid: 7560 - 10080 g
Linolenic acid: 693 - 1008 g
Calcium: 630000 - 819000 mg
Iron : 6930 - 11340 mg
Magnesium: 195300 - 258300 mg
Phosphorus: 441000 - 787500 mg
Potassium: 2961000 mg
Sodium: 1449000 mg (This is an upper limit - not a recommended allowance)
Zinc: 5040 - 6930 mg
Copper: 560700 - 567000 mcg
Manganese : 1134 - 1386 mg
Selenium: 34650 mcg
Vitamin A: 441000 - 567000 mg
Vitamin E: 9450 mg
Vitamin C: 47250 mg
Thiamin: 693 - 756 mg
Riboflavin: 693 - 819 mg
Niacin: 8820 - 10080 mg
B6: 819 mg
B12: 1512 mcg
Choline: 267750 - 346500 g
Vitamin K: 47250 - 56700 mcg
Folate: 252000 mcg
```

So our giant will be eating a whole lot, to say the least. For reference, an entire cow, properly butchered, yields approximately 513,713 calories. That would be a suitable entrée for our giant, with a side salad of an entire lettuce patch.

Comment: You are assuming that the dietary requirements scale linearly with mass. If this was true, elephants would starve.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your calories for an entire cow? I looked and couldn't find one.

Comment: The second answer on this Yahoo answers post, which includes calculations and sources: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081220234733AAfe5zj

Comment: 3kg of Potassium and 1.4kg of Sodium. Wow. In pure form that would make for quite a reaction.

Comment: You ought to express as more suitable units, e.g. kg not mg.

Comment: What's a mcg? Please use standard units.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, mcg is a standard unit. Micrograms.

Comment: @Cameron I typically abbreviate microgram as µg. Don't know about you, but I was taught to abbreviate "micro" (as in $10^{-6}$) as µ. If you don't have µ handy on your keyboard, `$\mu g$` (note the space; it matters here) gives $\mu g$ which is a decently close approximation. Of course, that doesn't work in literal code blocks such as you used in this answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, you have illustrated succinctly why I did not use that abbreviation...

Answer (score 3):

A 5'10" man should weight 129-174 lb, and would require 2,433-2,854.5 calories per day. A 50 ft tall giant would weigh 81,236-109,574 lb and require 305,852.4-358,839.1 calories per day.

[There are a few different animals that could provide enough calories.](https://qz.com/951238/a-scientist-calculated-the-nutritional-value-of-a-human-being/)

hare - 3,852
roe deer - 13,200
ibex - 45,780
beaver - 48,000
reindeer - 60,000
humans - 81,500
deer - 119,040
musk-ox - 140,400
red deer - 163,680
horse - 200,100
boar - 324,000
cow - 367,200
bear - 600,000

A man for breakfast, a deer for lunch and a deer for dinner every day should do just fine.

For the herbivorous giant, it would have to eat a ridiculous amount of food to stay alive.
apples - 520 per kg
bananas - 890 per kg
sweet potatoes - 1010 per kg
brown rice - 1230 per kg
avocado - 1600 per kg
chickpeas - 1640 per kg
bagels - 2500 per kg
macadamia nuts -7180 per kg

So unless your giant is eating 500 pounds of avocados a day, it's going to have to be a carnivore, or at least an omnivore.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use formulas that apply to normal humans and scale them up, this won't necessarily be 100% accurate, but neither are actual giants so let's go!

A fifty foot human would need to weigh between 9500 and 12750 lbs to be in a healthy range of BMI (18.5-24.9). That said, other ranges are certainly possible. To answer this question we will use multiple metabolic equations such as the harris-benedict equation and use activity multipliers that we use for real humans to come up with how many calories these giants need to sustain themselves each day.

[image]

So what do these numbers mean and what are the implications? These numbers represent your giant's total daily energy expenditure (or TDEE for short), this is how many calories your giants expend on a daily basis. Ranges were provided to suggest how individual differences are a thing, so a light male who is sedentary and burns 70k per day will likely continue to burn 70k per day. Being younger means energy expenditure is higher and being older means that energy expenditure is lower (values were calculated for 30 years of age). If a giant consumes less than his or her TDEE, that giant will lose weight. If a giant consumes more than his or her TDEE, that giant will gain weight.

This leads me to the implications. Your giants are likely going to be sedentary and light individuals unless food is simply incredibly abundant. Additionally, your giants are likely going to live in VERY small groups and be pretty territorial about land since getting sufficient food will likely be difficult. Your giants will likely be carnivores since vegetables tend to be light on calories. A grown cow weighing about 1000 lbs might provide about 650 lbs of meat which would give your giants somewhere in the range of 0.5-0.75 million calories. Enough to feed about 10 or so sedentary giants. Would they only want to eat meat though? Hard to say, it might not sustain them nutritionally and giants may die young due to nutritional deficiencies. Additionally because of the high energy costs of activity, giants would not go out of their way to be active.

Herbivorous giants are out of the question, but carnivorous and omnivorous giants are more plausible. Perhaps they operate as herders. Skyrim's concepts of giants keeping mammoths as company seems entirely logical from this perspective. I do not believe that they would do so well without a constant reliable food source however which circles back to them being territorial, not active unless the need arises, and not particularly large (more thin giants than anything else).

Comment: A 50 foot tall human would way much, much more than that. 9,500 lb would be severely anorexic. Past a certain height BMI does not really work.